# method setSuggestionsAdapter cannot be applied to given types

Tags: android, search, searchview, simplecursoradapter

I am trying [this code](https://gist.github.com/slightfoot/5514856) to implement a Search Activity but I am getting this error I am not sure how to solve it:

```
Error:(326, 19) error: method setSuggestionsAdapter in class SearchView cannot be applied to given types;
required: CursorAdapter
found: SearchSuggestionsAdapter
reason: actual argument SearchSuggestionsAdapter cannot be converted to CursorAdapter by method invocation conversion
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution is import SearchView as `import android.widget.SearchView;`
if you `import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;` so it can be the reason for the error.

Try this its work.
Thanks.